# Replace words in c

Tags: c, replace

I'm trying to create a function which replaces words. It also supports more than one argument (words) from the user. For example we a text file named "fesf" with these contents: "This is a test." When we type

./a.out test is < fesf.txt

it should replace "test" and "is" with "censor" in fesf.txt. (Notice that the new lines, arrangement should be the same as the original file, only the word is replaced). I created this function, but somehow it doesn't work. On return, it doesn't replace the argument. It just prints the original text.

Here's the function:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int main (int argc, char* argv[])

    {

     int i, j,c, state, wordlen, counter, found;
     char word[128];

     state = 0;
     wordlen = 0;

     while (( c= getchar())!= EOF) {

     if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c == 39))

      {
        state =1;
        word[wordlen] = c;
        wordlen++;

      }

       else if (state == 1)

      {
        state =0;
        found =0;


            }
```

Comment: Or, you know `isalpha(c) || c == 39`. What's so special about `´` though?

Comment: @EOF: OP wants "isn't", "can't", "it's" etc. treat as a single word.

Comment: The first comment fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `if` needs to capture both upper and lower case letters. One way to do that would be

```
if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c == 39))
```